# the meaning of past perfect continuous in that case

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

What indeed? While she was walking through the forest, she saw a wolf strolling slowly towards her, humming something to himself. A minute or so earlier, the wolf **had been watching** her from behind a tree, and had thought to himself, 'She'd make a nice juicy meal'. But as he didn't want to frighten her off he had decided to play it nice and cool, and so the nonchalant walk.

does it mean that a minute  or so earlier he had finished watching her from a tree or does it mean he was still watching her from a tree  as past perfect continuous is used I think he had finished

Comment: ***He had been watching her until*** a minute or so earlier. I have to say though animals don't stroll or play it cool. So, this has been messed up. The original Little Red Riding Hood is probably much better.

Comment: @Lambie The wolf in this story talks and wears a disguise. Strolling and playing it cool are easy tasks by comparison.